# Is a purely transcendental field extension regular?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The Wikipedia article on regular field extensions states that every purely transcendental extension is regular. However, there is no citation. Is this true, and can you give a good reference for this?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_extension

Answer (score 0):

This is true and follows directly from the definition. Let $K/k$ be a purely transcendental extension of $k$. Then by the definition of a purely transcendental extension, there are no elements of $K$ which are algebraic over $k$ except those already in $k$. So $\hat{k}=k$, and the definition of regularity is satisfied.